# Swapping values in python3

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I'm taking a course to learn python and they gave me an exercise to know what would be the outcome, here it is

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = a
b = c
a = b
print(a,b,c)
```

now, I thought the value would be 0, 20, 0. I thought of 0 because the C doesnt have a value and would be assigned by the memory but if it really did it would've been different then 0. I got confused with C but the outcome was 10,10,10. I ran the program and while searching for an answer I got to another question here where the person used the function *dis* and while using this function to see what the program was doing it gave me this

```
4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
            2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

5           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (20)
            6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

6           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
           10 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

7          12 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
           14 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

8          16 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
           18 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

10         20 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
           22 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
           24 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
           26 BUILD_TUPLE              3
           28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, in the question that I saw the answer contained the word *ROT_TWO* but in this one theres only *LOAD*,*STORE* and *RETURN*. In the other question there were only two variables but I thought it would still rotate them and print this word. I still dont know what is the program doing and why the outcome value was 10,10,10.

Heres the code that I wrote using the *dis* funciton.

```
from dis import dis

def value(a,b,c):
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a
    b = c
    a = b

    return a,b,c

dis(value)
```

Comment: "because the C doesnt have a value" - it definitely does after `c = a`

Comment: @ForceBru how come C has a value? Of my previous knowledge you need to either start C or *a = c* not the other way around. If this is common in python, sorry but I learned the other way and this is new to me.

Comment: I mean, can you do `c = 5`? The same for `c = a` if `a` has already been defined. After you do that, `c` will "have a value", so you'll be able to print it, pass to other functions, etc

Comment: I mean, I can do `c = 5` but in my mind, `c` wouldnt have a value if I did `c = a ` because it hasnt been initiated before hand. This is completely new to me, never seen it before but I can take it. Thanks.